# Comparing Calculation Error in Divergent Numerical Methods

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis

I'm not an expert in numerical methods, but I'm doing a simulation based on non-linear differential equations (General Relativity), there solutions has singularities, thus at some points numerical methods will break down.

The solution depends on some parameters, and I have a "control" equation, which is an expression of some calculated variables (for each point on the grid), the more the result is diverging out of zero, the bigger the error is, obviously, it will diverge to infinity near singularities.

So I want to figure out, at which parameters, my numeric method gives "best" result, but the problem is because control equation varies in the region $(-\infty,+\infty)$, so basically there is no way here to compare results for different parameter values, any standart way to do such a comparison?

P.S

I tried to calc quadratic difference of averages after eliminating all infinite values, also I tried to calc the average of inverse of the error, but it seems adhoc for me, and not sure that it is the right way to do this..

Comment: This question is extremely vague.  I do not think it can be answered unless it is stated more precisely.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I am not asking for sort of solution, I just asking if there is such methods, because I found none, then I will check how to fit it to may problem, explaining the simulation of gravitational collapse here is not a good practice, I believe.

Comment: I stand by my comment.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Ok then pls advice what is vague about it, or what additional information is needed to provide help.